# Why do I hear radio static when I turn on my 65 Amps Colour Boost pedal?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I have a [65 Amps Colour Boost pedal](https://youtu.be/4h_0oQcF8NQ), and unfortunately it's super noisy to the point of being completely unusable.  It sounds like it's picking up a radio signal, so I have loud static coming from my amp when I turn it on.  How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your guitar or the pedal might not be [shielded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding) to block radio frequencies. In this case, your guitar/pedal functions as a crude antenna and picks up radio signals. If your guitar is the culprit, the boost pedal only amplifies these radio signals to the point that they become audible. Make sure to try different boost pedals to see if they also amplify a radio signal.

To address this problem, the component that picks up the radio signals needs to be shielded. This is a common problem, so there are many instructions available online. Here are [two](https://www.premierguitar.com/articles/26279-mod-garage-how-to-shield-single-coil-pickups) [examples](https://www.seymourduncan.com/blog/installation-setup/how-to-shield-a-guitar).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking  that it could just be 60 cycle hum from the mains power. It might be some complicated issue with the electronics but I would check first for grounding issues or even getting a noise gate to cut all the excess noise out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's not 60-cycle hum.  It distinctly sounds like radio static (I think I can even hear faint, muffled voices, so whatever frequency is being picked up is probably between radio stations).  I can upload a recording of what I'm hearing if you'd like.